SQL case when in where condition
I'm trying to conver SQL to Python, have added the sqlfiddle here
This link has the input & expected output along with SQL as below:
select a.id, b.country, a.person, b.num
from tab2 a
left join tab1 b
on a.id=b.id
WHERE
case when b.country = 'Denmark' then 'Swiz' 
else b.country
end <> 'Russia';

And the requirement is to convert the above to Python, thanks in advance!

The python equivalent is ('Swiz' if b.country == 'Denmark' else b.country) != 'Russia'

Appreciate if you could share the complete code as answer @Barmar, thanks!

Okay.. I am a bit confused by your logic here.  You want to filter out all country not equal to 'Russia'?  Why do you need the case 'Denmark' return 'Swiz' when it is going to be dropped anyway?

I general it's better to use regular AND/OR in the WHERE clause instead of CASE expressions.

Your LEFT JOIN returns regular INNER JOIN result. Move the b table condition(s) from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result. (Or simply do an INNER JOIN if you want to keep the current result.)

Looking at how you create the tables and the code you've provided, you could do this:
import pandas as pd

data_tab1 = {
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'country': ['Denmark', 'Rome', 'Russia', 'Georgia', 'Austria'],
    'num': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
}

data_tab2 = {
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'person': ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5']
}

df_tab1 = pd.DataFrame(data_tab1)
df_tab2 = pd.DataFrame(data_tab2)

merged_df = pd.merge(df_tab2, df_tab1, on='id', how='left')

def case_condition(row):
    if row['country'] == 'Denmark':
        return 'Swiz'
    else:
        return row['country']

merged_df['country_case'] = merged_df.apply(case_condition, axis=1)
result_df = merged_df[merged_df['country_case'] != 'Russia']

final_result = result_df[['id', 'country', 'person', 'num']]

print(final_result)

which gives you
   id  country person  num
0   1  Denmark     p1   10
1   2     Rome     p2   20
3   4  Georgia     p4   40
4   5  Austria     p5   50


maybe you can use library / package with named "sqlite3", this package is you dont install because It is included in the standard library (since Python 2.5). or if you trouble with sqlite3 you can download here SQLite Download Page. and this is for the documentation SQLite Documentation Python
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:') # you can use for your db "testing.db", or ":memory:" for in-memory
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('''
CREATE TABLE tab1 (
  id INTEGER,
  country TEXT,
  num INTEGER
)
''')

cursor.execute('''
CREATE TABLE tab2 (
  id INTEGER,
  person TEXT
)
''')

cursor.execute('''
CREATE TABLE query_results (
  query TEXT,
  results TEXT
)
''')

conn.commit()

data_tab1 = [
    (1, 'Denmark', 10),
    (2, 'Rome', 20),
    (3, 'Russia', 30),
    (4, 'Georgia', 40),
    (5, 'Austria', 50)
]
cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO tab1 (id, country, num) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', data_tab1)

data_tab2 = [
    (1, 'p1'),
    (2, 'p2'),
    (3, 'p3'),
    (4, 'p4'),
    (5, 'p5')
]
cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO tab2 (id, person) VALUES (?, ?)', data_tab2)

conn.commit()

query = '''
SELECT a.id, b.country, a.person, b.num
FROM tab2 a
LEFT JOIN tab1 b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE CASE WHEN b.country = 'Denmark' THEN 'Swiz' ELSE b.country END <> 'Russia'
'''

cursor.execute(query)
results = cursor.fetchall()

for row in results:
    print(row)

header = 'id, country, person, num'

formatted_results = header + '\n' + '\n'.join([f'{row[0]}, {row[1]}, {row[2]}, {row[3]}' for row in results])

query_results = (query, formatted_results)
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO query_results (query, results) VALUES (?, ?)', query_results)
conn.commit()

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM query_results')
saved_query_results = cursor.fetchall()
for row in saved_query_results:
    print("Saved Query:", row[0])
    print("Saved Results:\n", row[1])

conn.close()

and for the result with my above code like this
(1, 'Denmark', 'p1', 10)
(2, 'Rome', 'p2', 20)
(4, 'Georgia', 'p4', 40)
(5, 'Austria', 'p5', 50)
Saved Query:
SELECT a.id, b.country, a.person, b.num
FROM tab2 a
LEFT JOIN tab1 b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE CASE WHEN b.country = 'Denmark' THEN 'Swiz' ELSE b.country END <> 'Russia'

Saved Results:
 id, country, person, num
1, Denmark, p1, 10
2, Rome, p2, 20
4, Georgia, p4, 40
5, Austria, p5, 50

maybe my answer can help you, keep healthy!
